# Insert new record if count of records with certain field is less than N in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have a table called Foos where each record references another record in table Bars.

When I attempt to insert a new record with bar_id = x into Foo:
If the count of existing Foos with bar_id = x is > 2, cancel the insert.
Else: insert the new record.

I am trying to get this done in one PostgreSQL query, if possible.

Here is my first attempt that doesn't work:

```
WITH c AS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foos WHERE bar_id = 3),
INSERT INTO foos(bar_id, title) VALUES(3, "Some thing") WHERE c < 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert from a subquery that returns rows only if there are less than 2 like rows:

```
insert into foos(bar_id, title)
select *
from (select 3, 'Some thing') x
where (select count(*) from foos where bar_id = 3) < 2
```